# What is the object of integral problems?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

We are learning about these in calculus and I can't grasp the concept. Is this similar to the anti-derivative ?

Comment: What is an "integral problem"? Something like "Find the integral $\int x^2\ dx$"?

Comment: Please make the body of the Question reasonably self-contained.  The title here is used to bear the burden of posing a problem, but with insufficient detail for a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral is usually called the anti-derivative, because integrating is the reverse process of differentiating. The fundamental theorem of calculus shows that antidifferentiation is the same as integration.
- google search

Answer (score 1):

Integrals are used to find the area under a curve.There are two types of integrals definite and indefinite.Indefinite are the same as the antiderivarive for example the integral of 2x is x^2.Definite integrals are basicaly indefinite integrals except with a constant and bounds.For example the definite integral of 2x from 0 to five is 25,however from two to five it is 5^2-2^2=21.